# Is there a way I can bind an input to my model and have a date filter in between?

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app is a field where a user can enter a date:

```
<input data-ng-model="modal.data.published" />
```

When submitted and received it will be in a form like this: `"2013-08-22T00:00Z"` . Note it must be in exactly this form where the "T00:00Z" is appended onto the string in the input field on submission and removed when the data comes from the server to the browser.

Is there a way that I can make the date binding work as follows:

```
Date Entered                  >>>>   Date sent to server
"2013-08-22"                         "2013-08-22T00:00Z"

Date sent from server         >>>>   Date appearing in the input field
"2013-08-22T00:00Z"                  "2013-08-22"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) provides API for the [ng-model](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) directive:

- Use `$formatters` to format a value from **model** -> **view**.
- Use `$parsers` to format and validate a value from the **view** -> **model**.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/osJz43R2wSOGh3yIIIiA?p=preview):

```
app.directive('niceDate', function($filter){
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs,ngModel){
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val){
        return $filter('date')(val,"yyyy-MM-dd");
      });
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
        return $filter('date')(val,"yyyy-MM-dd") + "T00:00Z";
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Markup:

```
<input type="text" nice-date data-ng-model="modal.data.published" />
```

I just showed a basic example, you should also add your custom validations.

Comment: Ilan - Thanks. I will look into this, try it out and uptdate